# SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, signtool

It's been 2 full days that I'm trying to sign my exe using SignTool and kSign. I bought a SSL certificate from COMODO for my domain (used for https on apache). Now I'm trying to sign my exe using the same certificate and the same private key used. I'm using the commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey example.com.key -in example.com.crt -export -out example.com.pfx
```

and trying to sign it

```
signtool /f example.com.pfx /p mypassword myexe.exe
```

and I always get: "SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria."

Whatever ways I found to generate PFX files from the Internet, it's always that same error message. I even tried to sign it with kSign and I get the same thing. What I am missing? Can I use a SSL certificate I bought for my web server for signing my exe files also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was, I tried to sign an application using a SSL certificate. That didn't work because SSl certificates is different from **code signing certificate**, which is the one I need.

Comment: Please complete the answer. So you bought CODE Signing certificate. Then how did you made the PFX file from the CERT file?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem by running

`certmgr.exe`

and then importing the certificate into the personal store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, my PFX file had an **expired certificate**.